# EditText display wrong text

Tags: android, rotation, android-edittext

i'm stuck whit a very strange problem. I have an editText in a dialog. If I open the dialog one time (tapping on a element of a ListView) and do some stuff all ok. If I open the dialog the next time (tapping on a different element of a ListView) the editText display the same value of the first time.

```
toast(profilesList.get(toEdit).get(NAME).toString()); //toast say Bob
et_profileName.setText(profilesList.get(toEdit).get(NAME).toString()); //I see Alice
```

Another strange thing: if I rotate the display the text change in "BobAlice". If I close the dialog, and then I reopen it, all work well and the dialog display the right Strings.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
et_profileName is in a dialog that opens when you click an item in the ListView.

More code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    ...
    et_profileName= (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_profileName);
    ...
}
```

Here is when I call the dialog:

```
showDialog(DIALOG_EDIT_PROFILE);
toast(profilesList.get(toEdit).get(NAME).toString());
et_profileName.setText(profilesList.get(toEdit).get(NAME).toString());
```

Also don't work if I put

```
et_profileName= (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_profileName);
```

before the et_profileName.setText(...)

Comment: maybe et_profileName is referencing the first EditText

Comment: Is the EditText in the ListView or is it in a Dialog that opens when you click an item in the ListView

Comment: My suggestion is to add more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Should override the `onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)` to prepare a 
managed dialog before it is being shown.

Added this code, it works:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog){
    et_profileName= (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_profileName);
    if(id==DIALOG_EDIT_PROFILE){
        et_profileName.setText(profilesList.get(toEdit).get(NAME).toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks you all!